# where is the location of angular-cli in ubuntu

Tags: pycharm, angular-cli

hello I am trying to create a new angular cli project in pycharm 
I installed

nodejs v8.9.3

npm v5.5.1

@angular/cli

but pycharm asks me to specify angular-cli package

[image]

I don know where the package is located
thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `which @angular/cli` in terminal to find location.

Comment: @angular/cli not found thats the result 
this is while I have angular CLI version 1.6.0 when I type ng --version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular CLI is localed in Ubuntu (16.04 LTS, in my case) in **`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli`**. See screenshot below. Notice that you must have installed angular-cli first in order to find it in this location.

[image]